# Validating javascript event handler inside html DIV

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, w3c-validation, xhtml-transitional

i'm using the following javascript event handler to handle dynamically populated unavailable images in the database.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function blank_image_handler() {
    document.getElementById("imageplaceholder").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

```
<body>
<div id="imageplaceholder"> <img src="image/thumbnail/<?php echo $row_images['image_link']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row_images['image_caption']; ?>" onerror='blank_image_handler();' /> </div>
</body>
```

This event handler is serving the purpose properly but it is not validated during w3c html validation.

The error i receive during validation is `there is no attribute "onerror"`

By the way my doc type is xhtml transitional

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Answer (score 1):

Your DTD is http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
If you look at the list of supported events in the DTD:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-transitional.dtd_events
There is no 'onerror' event, and that's why w3c validator reports an error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `onerror` attribute in the specification, even if browsers might implement it.

The better version would be to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function blank_image_handler() 
   {
      document.getElementById("imageplaceholder").style.display = "none";
   }

   var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
   image.addEventListener('error', blank_image_handler, true);
</script>
```

Of course you have to give the image the id `myImage` then. And you should move he script to the end of the html (which is recommended anyway).

Comment: should i use any attribute within `imageplaceholder` `div` to trigger on the function in this case or how shall i switch on the function in that div or shall the function be executed automatically based on DOM event `addEventListener`?

Comment: `ie` produces the following example error `Message: 'image' is null or not an object
Line: .........
Char: ........
Code: ............
URI: http://................
` moreover it `ie` cant hide empty image place holder.

Comment: yes, i changed the code to
`<div id="imageplaceholder"> <img id ="myImage" src="image/thumbnail/<?php echo $row_images['image_link']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row_images['image_caption']; ?>" />`. have i done anything wrong? Thanks,

Comment: Did you move the script to the end of the HTML file?

Comment: Yes, i moved the function just before `</html>` tag which causes the following error: `Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: ...
Char: ....
Code: ...
URI: http:/............` means this is not the right place to put the function.

Comment: Ok, my bad, at the end of the `<body></body>` tag, just before `</body>`

Comment: Btw. Which version of the IE are you using? Does it work with other browsers? (All version below 9 are pretty crappy ..)

Comment: although i'm using ie8, of course i shall prefer a cross versions solution.

Answer (score 0):

insted of using 'onerror' you could do the following in a script tag:

```
  document.getElementById("imageplaceholder").addEventListener("error",blank_image_handler,false);
```

Comment: without triggering the function using any attribute in imageplaceholder div ie keeps displaying a red cross image place holder if `addEventListener` is assumed true.

Comment: your question isn't clear to me. i've included the code (code in body tag) in my question where the function `blank_image_handler` was triggered using `onerror` attribute. although based on the document type my code is wrong it was serving the purpose properly except validation.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/Jc2wB/  it listens to the 'click' event than the error, so you can actually see it working

Comment: since images are being populated dynamically on page load `click` attribute won't be applicable here. the attributes should be something like `load`, `initialize` etc. compatible with document type.

Comment: Sure, click is just an example here. The point is that instead of using 'onerror' inside your html you can add the respective event listener inside your js script. Does this not answer your question?